# left shift "stuck " on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, accessibility, shift

I'm having a hard time with a "stuck" left shift key.

my sister complained she is getting symbols instead of numbers using her netbook.
after some time I fired up the on screen keyboard (winr+r>"osk")
and to my surprise, the left shift key was in some kind of toggle mode.

since then I'm trying to inject registry keys to disable accessibility futures like stickykeys etc. to no avail.

tough luck all http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/Windows-vista/disable-the-irritating-sticky-filter-keys-popup-dialogs/ check box are disabled

What's going on? How can I fix this?

Operating system is Windows 7 Home Premium, SP1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot to another operating system of your choice ([DSL is small](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/)), and see if the shift key works as expected.  If not, you have a hardware problem (crumbs/soup/coke/coffee in the keyboard?)

Also, if you have a field in your BIOS that lets you type and reflects shift-state, you can use that to test instead of booting to another OS.

Comment: thanks guys for the great replays.  
the netbook i was using has some form of instant on OS that i used to check the problem. it was there so i connected an external keyboard and problem is not showing on that so i suspect it is a hardware problem. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

[SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) may help.

Comment: this might be my last hope, i'll just disable the left shift alltogther. but being an international user i need the Lshift+alt combo.

Comment: @yoshco: I found another solution that seems to fix exactly what you're describing -- take a look at my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may have to do with the BIOS of the motherboard of the computer.

When the computer first boots up you usually get a splash screen that says `Press [key] to enter Setup`.  Oftentimes the key is F1, or F12.

Inside the BIOS screen there can be a 'keys' setup page and you can change the function of certain keys.

I had a similar experience with a laptop where when the computer would boot the `Fn` key was automatically on and whenever you typed anything on the right half of the keyboard, the secondary function of each key was used instead of the primary function (letters).

Comment: i had the fn key set for 5 sec sticky, disabled it but doesnt change my error. but cool to know, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**[I think] This might be by design**...

Go to `Regional and Language options->Change Keyboards->Advanced Key Settings` and for `To turn off Caps Lock`, select:

> Press the CAPS LOCK key

Comment: no, it was allready set that way.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, Left Alt + Left Shift switch between Keyboard Language. It can appear that Shift Lock is on. Try That.

Comment: It is not clear how keyboard language switching relates to shift lock. Could you please explain?